# Is there an API to upload WADL files into my Apigee Console ToGo Account?

Tags: documentation, apigee

Something similar to API Gateway, which through the Management API enables the deployment of API bundles in it, so uploading the WADL file doesn't require going through the UI every time there's change for it and uploading the console becomes a cURL command away, which could also be even automated by deploying it via scripting languages.

Also, is there a way to create more than one console per account? So far, I've been only able to create only one Console ToGo one account per user under Apigee Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working on supporting multiple Consoles per account. This should be available in next month's release.

As for an API to update the WADL, we have an undocumented API that is likely to change with next month's release. Short answer is that you should have an API as well in next month's release.

Comment: Since this answer is dated Feb 3, can I ask if there is now an existing API to update the wadl.xml for a specific console?

Answer (score 0):

No -- there's only a web form and Authentication is handled using Apigee SSO cookies so you can't even really fake it with curl.